# How do I send user to a URI on MouseLeftButtonUp?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

This question is for Windows Phone 7.

I'd like to send the user to a specific external URI when the entire ListBox item is clicked (not HyperLinkButton). I already have a MouseLeftButtonUp event handler for the item. At this point, I can't find a way to navigate the user to the URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event on your ListBox and navigate to the URI in the event handler.
The [AddedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.addeditems%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property of the [SelectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) object passed to the event handler can then be used to retrieve the item that the user selected.

Or you can also bind the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property of your ListBox to one of your properties and navigate to the URI in the set accessor of this property.